# angular2 render component before oninit

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, page-refresh

I have following code snippets

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../shared/services/authentication.service";
import { User } from "./user";
import { UserService } from "./user.service";

@Component({
    templateUrl:'./user.component.html'
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit{
    user: User;

    constructor(
        private _userService: UserService,
        private _authService:AuthenticationService){
    }

    ngOnInit(){

        let user = this._userService.getUser();

        if(!user){
            this._authService.getLoggedUser().subscribe(
                user => {
                    this.user = user;
                    this._userService.setLoggedUser(user);
                }
            );

            this._userService._loggedUser$.subscribe(
                user => {
                    this.user = user;
                }
            )
        }else{
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
}
```

this working fine with first route initializing(/user/profile) with `else` block.But when user **refresh the browser window** I made a request again to the server and get user back and render my html component( `if(!user)` block ).here is html view

```
<form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Profile</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mobile</label>
                <input name="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.mobileNumber">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email" disabled>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And I have the AppComponent and it will do the same inside `onInit`(get user via http call if not exist).The problem is when I render my UserComponent on page refresh first before finishing the init method of userComponent it will navigate to AppComponent init method and just after that `user.component.html` will crash without user data saying `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.and again it will redirect to onInit of UserComponent and but at this time user html had already rendered and carshed.

How can I fix this scenario and Is there a best way to handle a situation like this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can put your `<form>` inside a `<div *ngIf="user">..</div>` and this component is loading only once you have some values inside your user. so you will not get that error.

```
<div *ngIf="user">
     <form> <fieldset>
            <legend>Profile</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
            </div>
           .............
           .............
    </form>
</div>
```

there is one more way you can use resolve in your route so only when your resolve is done then only user.component will start.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  ...
  { 
    path: 'contact/:id',
    component: ContactsDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
      contact: 'contact'
    }
  }
];
```

read from here about resolve http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: thanks Amit.it works.. and thanks again for the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

What about this? Show the form once user is in. 
`<fieldset *ngIf="user">`